# How to config error pages in WebLogic Server 12c

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, spring-security, weblogic

I developed a `Spring Boot 2.1.0` web application and `Weblogic 12c` shows the default *401 Unauthorize* page, but it works correctly in the `Tomcat` and error pages are application error page's.

I want to change `Weblogic` error pages (specially 401) and show my application error pages.

Can any one explain solution step by step?

If you have any suggestions that can be help me, please add comment or answer.

Thanks.